# Device Handles

Tags: c++, xcode

I m trying to get the number of device handles used by a process at a particular instance.
I am using x-code on Mac 10.6.6 . I have tried using lsof but no satisfactory result .
Please help.....

Comment: what is the result of isof and why not satisfactory? In unix-like systems there are only several commands that can let you know opened files: fuser, isof, fstat..

Comment: The command is lsof and yes it is giving the no. of file handles but what I needed is the no. of device handles separately.....   It would be more helpful if I can get any low level API so that I can use it in my c++ code....

Comment: you could try using strace to get that information

Answer (score 0):

You could look in /proc/nnnn/fd/ (where nnn is the pid) but you'd still have to count the files there.